# Uploading a Word Document to Sharepoint using SaveBinaryDirect() resulting in corrupted document

Tags: client-object-model, file-upload

I am uploading a document to sharepoint site using client object model.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\UlDoc.docx", FileMode.Open))
{
    File.SaveBinaryDirect(_cc, "/demo/Word%20Docs/temp.docx", stream, true);
}
```

The file is uploading to the site with same filename but it is getting corrupted (only 18kb) instead of the actual file size. Any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is helper method to return the bytes form the stream. Please let me know if you face any issue with this code.

I am using the same code in SilverLight Application.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input, long fileSize)
        {

            //long fileSize = input.Length;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];

            //   byte[] newArray = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Use   var localFile = new FileCreationInformation() for saving a file using client Object model.

```
List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("test"); 
                var localFile = new FileCreationInformation(); 
                localFile.Content = ReadFully(_openFileDialog.File.OpenRead(),
_openFileDialog.File.Length);
                // localFile.Overwrite = true;

                string FileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_openFileDialog.File.Name);

                string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_openFileDialog.File.Name);


                    localFile.Overwrite = true; 
                    localFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_openFileDialog.File.Name);


                file = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(localFile);
                context.Load(file);
                text= file.ListItemAllFields;
                text["Title"] = file.Name;

                text.Update();
                context.Load(file.ListItemAllFields);
                context.ExecuteQueryAsync(sucess, failed);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can see it will work as I had similar code already implemented to upload a file given a "local filepath" of the document. However I am trying to upload when a stream is passed (part of the requirement as I get a stream from Document automation app), and using "SaveBinaryDirect" as the above approach fails with large files (word documents).

Comment: Increasing the Maximum Message Size http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx

Comment: +1 For your effort, But I still prefer using SaveBinaryDirect as That is the problem here. Not any workarounds. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only the default buffer is loaded at maximum and that is why is corrupted. Try looping through the array as such :

```
FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(<file_location_here>);
            byte[] content = new byte[fstream.Length];
            fstream.Read(content, 0, (int)fstream.Length);
            fstream.Close();
```

Now the FileStream should have it all loaded.

use then an SPWeb previously opened and the method Add as in

```
using (SPSite _site= new SPSite("URL"))
{
 using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb()){
_web.Files.Add("<FULL LIB PATH>/<NAME OF THE FILE>", content);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have already tried reading the file stream the way you suggested, but it is saving a blank file instead of the actual file. And I cannot use SPWeb as I am using client object model and the upload is from client side.

Comment: Oh, i didn't catch on the C-OM. There are valid example on how to upload it via OM (assuming Managed OM - right?). See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx and here http://blog.isrichtig.de/Lists/Beitraege/Post.aspx?List=1d9a40b5-d004-4ace-8b09-2ba5b094501c&ID=118&Web=c6f338be-ae15-4558-a9d5-6cb4b33e4f50

Comment: Nice links, thank you. I am exactly doing it as in the examples in your links, (you can see my code in the question). The only problem is corrupted document.